# The resource file for 'ClassA' class cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my class library project,I have a resource file(.resx).
From this I am building a dll(Satelite assembly),which is being referenced in another separate project(Visual studio 2003 project).

When I call this dll ,its saying resource file not found for ClassA.I have set its property to Embedded Resource.Could somebody help me please,Whether I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the "Access Modifier" to public in your .resx file?

Here is where the access modifier is located:

[image: Resx file sample image]